# Высота дочерней формы больше чем главная форма MDI-приложения

Tags: delphi

В MDI-приложении есть главная форма uMain и дочерние формы uChartAcc, uGas.
В клиентской области главной формы на экране не помешается нижняя часть дочерних форм и, следовательно, появляется вертикальная прокрутка. Хочу чтобы дочерняя форма полностью поместилась в главной форме между toolbar и statusbar, без вертикальной полосы прокрутки.

[image: главная форма]
[image: child form]
[image: child form at runtime]

Если выставить WindowState дочерней формы на wsMaximized нижняя часть формы все равно не видна до конца. Кроме этого, в правом угле, на Main Menu накапливаются триады кнопок.

[image: maximized chiled form]

```
Главная форма:
Formstyle:MDIForm 

дочерние формы:
Formstyle:MDIChild 
Align- alClient или alCustom
Position-пробовал poDefaultPosOnly, poDefault, poDesigned
utoSize:false
```

Пробовал установки размеров формы поместить в процедурах OnCreate, OnShow, OnResize но ничего не меняется.

**unit Umain;**

```
    procedure TFmain.MDIChildCreated(const childHandle : THandle);
    begin
      mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.AddObject(TForm(FindControl(childHandle)).Caption, TObject(childHandle));
      mdiChildrenTabs.TabIndex := -1 + mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.Count;
    end;

    procedure TFmain.MDIChildDestroyed(const childHandle : THandle);
    var
      idx: Integer;
    begin
      idx := mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.IndexOfObject(TObject(childHandle));
      mdiChildrenTabs.Tabs.Delete(idx);
    end;



    procedure TFmain.NChartAccClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      application.CreateForm(TfChartAcc, fChartAcc);
     fChartAcc.Show;
    end;

    procedure TFmain.realisatia1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      application.CreateForm(TFgas, Fgas);
      Fgas.Show;
    end;

    end.
```

**unit UChartAcc;**

```
    procedure TfChartAcc.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    begin
     action:=caFree;
    end;


    procedure TfChartAcc.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     Left:=0;
     Top:=Fmain.Toolbar.Height+Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height;
     Height:=Fmain.ClientHeight-Fmain.Toolbar.Height-Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height-Fmain.StatusBar.Height-2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
     Width:=Fmain.ClientWidth- 2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);

      FMain.MDIChildCreated(self.Handle);
    end;


    procedure TfChartAcc.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     FMain.MDIChildDestroyed(self.Handle);
    end;

    procedure TfChartAcc.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     {
     Left:=0;
     Top:=Fmain.Toolbar.Height+Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height;
     Height:=Fmain.ClientHeight-Fmain.Toolbar.Height-Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height-Fmain.StatusBar.Height-2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
     Width:=Fmain.ClientWidth- 2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
     }
    end;





    procedure TfChartAcc.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     Left:=0;
     Top:=Fmain.Toolbar.Height+Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height;
     Height:=Fmain.ClientHeight-Fmain.Toolbar.Height-Fmain.MDIChildrentabs.height-Fmain.StatusBar.Height-2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
     Width:=Fmain.ClientWidth- 2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
    end;

    end.
```

[см.Project1](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wQRFXLwDREQrWwmN3bucXTi8qamPGPAl?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Обязательные **3 условия вместе**:

childForm.align=none, WindowsState=wsMaximezed и никакой код установки размеров формы в OnCreate. [image: см. рисунок]